# FTP 7.5 Restrict by IP Address

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7, ftp

How do I restict FTP access to a single IP Address in FTP 7.5?  There used to be a dialog box in FTP 6.
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The interface changed a bit, but it's still there.

In the IIS Manager, select the root of your FTP site.  In the right side panel, there's an icon for FTP IPv4 Address and Domain Restrictions.  That will allow you to add both Allow and Deny rules based on a specific IP Address or a range.  You use the Edit Feature Sets link on the right side to set the default access (Allow all or deny all).